# Custom Task on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i wanted to make a new Task on my app, for later make a tracking for it... But i think the way i'm trying is not good.
This is what i'm trying:

```
public async Task NombreEvento(string json)
    {
        var c = new Jumper.Core.Client.Client();
        var item2 = await c.CreateDefaultItem();
        Jumper.Core.Model.TrackingItem item = item2;
        item.Type = Jumper.Core.Model.TrackingTypeEnum.Custom;
        item.Json = json;
        item.RunningSeconds = 0;
        var t = new Jumper.Core.Services.ServiceFactory();
        var service = await t.serviceFactory.TrackingService.AddItem(item);
    }
```

My problem is that i can't use the function CreateDefaultItem...
Error on Client() is: Using the generic type Jumper.Core.Client.Client requires 4 type arguments.

Here is the function CreateDefaultItem:

```
namespace Jumper.Core.Client
{
public sealed class Client
     <TBaseSaveData,
    TDeviceServiceHelper,
    TGeoLocationService,
    TNetworkService>
    where TBaseSaveData : BaseSaveDataService, new()
    where TDeviceServiceHelper : IDeviceServiceHelper, new()
    where TGeoLocationService : IGeoLocationService, new()
    where TNetworkService : INetworkService, new()
{

    private readonly int appId;
    private readonly string appVersion;
    private readonly ServiceFactory<TBaseSaveData,
        TDeviceServiceHelper,
        TGeoLocationService,
        TNetworkService> serviceFactory;

    #region Constructors

    internal Client
        (int appId, string appVersion)
    {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appVersion = appVersion;

        this.serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory<TBaseSaveData,
        TDeviceServiceHelper,
        TGeoLocationService,
        TNetworkService>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    public async Task SendItem(TrackingTypeEnum trackingType, bool flush)
    {
        TrackingItem item = await CreateDefaultItem();
        item.Type = trackingType;

        if (trackingType != TrackingTypeEnum.Background)
        {
            item.RunningSeconds = 0;
        }

        await this.serviceFactory.TrackingService.AddItem(item, flush);
    }

    public async Task<TrackingItem> CreateDefaultItem()
    {
        Tuple<double, double> location = await this.serviceFactory.GeoLocationService
            .GetUnifiedGeoLocation();

        var assemblyService = this.serviceFactory.AssemblyInfoService;
        var deviceService = this.serviceFactory.DeviceServiceHelper;
        var seconds = (DateTime.UtcNow - this.serviceFactory.TrackingService.StartTime).TotalSeconds;
        TrackingItem item = new TrackingItem()
        {

            //APP
            AppId = this.appId,
            RunningSeconds = (int)seconds,
            AppVersion = this.appVersion,
            Language = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName,
            Country = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Substring(3, 2),

            //Navigation
            Json = TrackingItem.NULL
        };
        return item;
    }
}
```

I have the same problem for function serviceFactory (with the same error).

Can anyone help me please?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to write something like:

```
var c = new Jumper.Core.Client.Client<Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4>();
```

Although I am unfamiliar with that library you are using.
Is that the whole listing right there? Are you even supposed to create instances of `Client` manually?

Comment: Yes, but i have to use that? <TBaseSaveData,
    TDeviceServiceHelper,
    TGeoLocationService,
    TNetworkService> i don't know how to access them here...

Comment: Neither do I. What is that `Jumper` framework anyway, it is not standard. Have you looked at the sample documentation?

Comment: Jumper is and SDK that i created for tracking events on apps. I don't know what I have to show you for make you that easy.

Comment: You created it? So why did you add those template parameters then?